# Problemas de ejecucion en hosting

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

Buen dia,
Tengo un codigo PHP en mi localhost, con MySQl, funciona perfecto, pero cuando lo pase a produccion en el hosting, algunas cosas dejaron de funcionar, ambos servidores estan en php7, deje una fraccion del codigo que dejo de funcionar (entre otros)

```
                           <?php if ($mostrarg['cesan']=== '1'){ ?>
                        <label> <input type="checkbox"  class="form-control" id="cesan" name="cesan" checked> Cesantias</label>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <label> <input type="checkbox"  class="form-control" id="cesan" name="cesan"> Cesantias </label>  
                        <?php }?>
```

En el localhost, cumple la funcion el check, si es 1 el campo lo marca, si no esta desmarcado, pero en el hosting WEB no cambia el estado, que me faltara configurar?,
Descubri que si funciona, pero cuando cargo el Form debo actualizar la pagina para que muestro los datos reales, me vuelvo loco. :(

Comment: Buenas, puedes postear si te da algun error? asi es complicado saberlo

Comment: No, carga la pagina, sin ningun error, pero no hace lo que tiene que hacer :(, tampoco me carga un simple campo de texto,

Comment: ese '1' lo recibes como una cadena (string) o como un numero?? prueba a quitarle las comillas, talvez por el tipo de datos es que PHP no lo ejecuta. ademas usas ===, prueba con ==

Comment: Tienes activado la directiva display_error = True en el php,init? si no es asi activala ejecuta el proceso y comparte el error que te pinta en el html. Los logs del servidor web (si usas apache, /var/log/apache2/hostxx.log) podrias compartirlo?

Comment: Lo raro es que si le doy F5 a la pagina si refresca bien el furmulario, osea, muestra los datos de la BD.